# Find hostname of user that fired trigger

Tags: sql-server-2012, audit

I am using a script to make and audit table for a table in a database. I have triggers for INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE. Currently it writes suser_sname() to one of the fields in the audit table.

My problem is that every user has the same login name. By executing sp_who2 I can see that the HostName is different for each user.

However, when I try to use HOST_NAME() it seems like I get the IP address for the server instead.

What function can I use to get the HostName of the user who fired the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you i guess.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/907/how-to-find-server-name-and-local-machine-name-in-sql-server

You need to set it first.